# Ratios of similar triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

This is a basic question, and based on my thoughts I really think this is true, but I just want some verification. If I have similar triangles, are the ratios between two sides of one triangle equal to the ratio of the corresponding sides on the other triangle?

Comment: What is your definition of *similar*?

Comment: @lhf I see where you are going :) Of course - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaling operation that defines similarity scales all sides by the same factor. So when going from one triangle to the other, $\frac{\text{side A}}{\text{side B}}$ becomes$\frac{k×\text{side A}}{k×\text{side B}}$ and the two instances of $k$ cancel. You are right.

Comment: Thanks:) I just needed that verification. Are the ratio of the angles of a triangle the same as the ratios of it's side (in any triangle - within itself)

Comment: @Burt That is also true.

Answer (score 1):

In geometry, we say that two objects are *similar* if they have the same shape; more precisely, if one shape can be turned into the other by a combination of enlargement, rotation, and reflection. None of these transformations alter the ratios between the lengths of the sides of the triangles. Hence, two triangles can only be similar if they have the same ratios of lengths. And *if* these ratios are the same, then the two triangles are similar.